# Comparing a chosen word with a single-letter guess in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm relatively new to programming, and I'm currently working on a Python Hangman game. I have a list of words, and my goal is to randomly select one word from the list. Then, I ask the user to guess a single letter. However, I'm facing a logical issue when comparing the chosen word (which is a complete word) with the user's single letter guess.

To overcome this issue, I decided to split the chosen word into individual letters so that I can compare them with the user's guess. For example, I split "baboon" into "b", "a", "b", "o", "o", "n".

Here's my code:

**Here is my code.**

```
import random

word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

chosen_word = list(random.choice(word_list))

guess = input("Input a letter: ").lower()

for n in range(0, len(chosen_word)):
    if guess == chosen_word[n]:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

Now, I noticed that the instructor's code achieves the same result with much simpler logic. They define a variable called letter, which appears to be a single letter string. However, in my opinion, comparing this letter with the complete word chosen_word doesn't make sense and should always result in a "Wrong" answer. For example, comparing "a" to "baboon" would not give a "Right" answer.

**Here is the instructor's code for reference.**

```
import random

word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

if letter == guess in chosen_word:
    print("Right")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Am I misunderstanding something here? It seems that the instructor's code is simpler, but I don't see how the comparison of letter with the complete word chosen_word can produce correct results. I appreciate any insights or clarifications. Thank you!

Comment: Where is letter defined in the instructors code? Shouldn't it be if guess in chosen_word?

Comment: The in operator checks for membership in an array, and a string is an array of characters. https://realpython.com/python-in-operator/#pythons-in-operator

Comment: `
if guess in chosen_word:
    print("Right")
    print(chosen_word)
`
gives you
`
Guess a letter: Aa
Right
aardvark`
is this not strange, there is no capital A into the choosen word. You should say the customer, what is expected. String is a list of characters and the keyword “in” checks if this character is a member of the list.

Comment: You need a new instructor. Tell him/her to look out for a NameError exception when that code is used

Comment: Thank you guys! I guess for now I'm going to stick to my code for an easier understanding as a fresh noob.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

letter = guess.isalpha()

if letter == guess in chosen_word:
    print("Right")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

You could do it in this way maybe give letter the same value as guess and also add "isalpha" to make sure that it is a letter from alphabet.

Comment: Many thanks mate, since the hanging man game needs to replace the blanks with relative item in the chosen_word, I guess the proper way is still by using range. If it's only about right and wrong, your answer is perfect.